# Bootstrap Toggle Tweets Not Showing Properly on Smartphones

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

Www.anchoreducation.co.uk

This website I have built is responsive. It uses bootstrap 3.0 as it's base, and when viewed on a smartphone, the right hand side bar is hidden by default, with a small toggle button appearing on home page.

If the website is viewed on a smartphone which is held in portrait, and the toggle button is pressed, not all of the content is showed. It cuts off the tweet feed and the logo / testimonials are only just visible. However, if the site is viewed landscape on a smartphone, it all works fine.

My client is eager to get this cosmetic error fixed, as am I, but I can't work out what's wrong in the code. If anyone could help I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that you are using offcanvas but it is already modified so - you can add this to off canvas.css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation : portrait) {
    .row-offcanvas-right.active {
        right: 70%;
    }
    .sidebar-offcanvas {
        width:66%
    }
    .row-offcanvas-right .sidebar-offcanvas {
        right: -65%
    }
}
```

It will create some more space for right box if device is in portrait orientation.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much! I had no idea about the orientation thing. Thanks again!